# Commenting and auto-spacing

Tags: android-studio

When I comment a line out (CMD + /), the double slash appears at the beginning of the line and there 's a big space between the double slashes and the code:

```
    @Override protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        int alarmType       = AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME;
        long updateInterval = AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES;
//        long updateInterval = 1000 * 10;
        long timeToRefresh  = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + updateInterval;
```

is there a way to make the double slashes appear right in front of the code like this ?:

```
    @Override protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        int alarmType       = AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME;
        long updateInterval = AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES;
      //long updateInterval = 1000 * 10;
        long timeToRefresh  = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + updateInterval;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go to Settings and under Editor > Code Style > Java, uncheck this option.
[image]